# Updating attributes on several indexes in array. Using mongoid in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Inside my test database, I would like to trigger a "new_item" flag for testing.  The method already works in my tests.  So now I am setting the created_at and published_at fields of all records to 1 month ago, then want to set a select few in an array to be published yesterday.

I use the following code to set all then 1 record:  (In Rails 3.1.1)

```
yesterday = Time.now - 1.day
last_month = Time.now - 1.month
Item.update_all(:created_at => last_month, :published_at => last_month)
Item.visible[1].update_attributes(:created_at => yesterday, :published_at => yesterday)
```

Which works.  However, how can I select multiple records in that array instead of just the [1] index.   ie.  [1,4,5,8,10]  etc.

I believe update_attributes doesn't work on multiple records.  And I'm not sure how to select multiple indexes in an existing array.

I hope this makes sense...

Thanks in advance,

Adam.

Answer (score 0):

`update_attributes` is an instance method, i.e. it will work on an instance of the model. `update_all` is a criteria method(may be model class delegates to criteria) and can be chained to mongoid criteria. If you have some criteria for obtaining the indexes of documents on array you can do:

```
Item.visible.where(:some_other_field => "some_other_value").
    update_all(:created_at => last_month, :published_at => last_month)
```

If you don't have a criteria, but are handpicking the items, you can do:

```
# instead of `model_array.update_attributes`
ids = model_array.map(&:id)
Item.all.for_ids(ids).update_all(:created_at => last_month, :published_at => last_month)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Rubish... I can see how that can work for a scope.  I think my issue is more seeing how to select multiple instances by index in an array.  Like selecting [1,3,9] to say, edit the first, 3rd and 9th record in the collection.